# Adobe Illustrator alternative for the Mac?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, adobe

I need to be able to view and edit AI files on OS X.
How can do that without Adobe Illustrator?

Comment: Is there an Adobe Illustrator alternative, that makes efficient usage of multiple-core processors? (note: some more professional, possibly more expensive, but also faster alternative to illustrator)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use [Inkscape](http://www.inkscape.org/) (Open source/Freeware) to open .AI-Files.

Answer (score 5):

Affinity Designer, which is an amazing vector app

https://affinity.serif.com/en-gb/

Answer (score 1):

Preview.app can view AI files, if anyone needs just read them.

Comment: The preview App can only view the PDF compatible part of an AI file. If the file wasn't saved as PDF compatible then it will only show a white rectangle with a default warning (long) text.